# Reload gazetteer of UIMA Concept Mapper in runtime without restarting the UIMA pipeline

Tags: nlp, mapper, uima

Currently, I'm using UIMA concept mapper in UIMA pipeline to tag entities in text.
But the problem is that each time I change the gazetteer of one concept mapper annotator, I have to restart the whole UIMA pipeline. That means I have to restart all annotators in the pipeline.

Is there any way to reload the gazetteer for the concept mapper without restarting the pipeline?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us why you want to reload the gazetteer.. . If you want to change the gazetteer based on input annotations you should be able to do this dynamically in code. Alternatively you could create multiple annotators with different gazetteers. Another option is to save the CAS prior to the concept mapper and then load it in as needed for each different gazetteer. It all depends what you want to do.

Comment: If you mean that you have a pipeline that runs continuously (e.g. as an online service) and over time you improve some of the annotators (by updating gazetteers), you could look into using UIMA-AS to deploy individual AEs independently. Then you could start up updated annotators and have them register with the broker as a drop-in replacement for the earlier version. However, I would be surprised if that was ever worth the effort over just restarting the complete pipeline.